# Hive: why CTAS can't read a file whereas select query can

Tags: java, hadoop, hiveql, hive-udf, hive-query

I have put my file at `/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/test_abspath` and want to read first line using my UDF. 
When I ran it using `select test('ABCD','ABCD');` I could read the file but when I tried it using `Create table as test_tb select test(name,'ABCD') from another_table` it fails. in second case `f1.exist() was true` but `f1.canRead() was false` I tried changin read write permission by chmod 777, it didn't worked.

Java code to read file is as follows:

```
public class config {
  public static final String confFilePath = "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/test_file
  public static void init(){    
        BufferedReader br;
       try {    
            File f1 = new File(confFilePath);
            if (f1.exists())
            {   if (f1.canRead()){

                br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( confFilePath ));
                String line;
                line = br.readLine();
                str = line;
                logger.info("inside init");
                }
                else{
                    str = "can't read";
                }
            }
```

In case of `select test('ABCD','ACBD')` it reads first line of test_file successfully and in case of `Create table as test_tb select test(name,'ABCD') from another_table` it return `can't read` String.

Edit: If this is about adding serde.jar then please redirct me to correct jar to download.
HDP sandbox version 2.6.5

Comment: Is the file you want to read local or on HDFS? your `select` query might work because it's not running on cluster hence Hive has no problems with finding the file, while `create` query is running on cluster. Try to add the file to distributed cache with `add file`, then read it with Java code. Keep in mind that you need to change the file location as it's in the root folder, e.g. `./test_file`

Comment: can you please explain more on " 'create' runs on cluster" .  I observe that when I tried to get working directory of select its same as my current directory whereas for Create query its /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root. Can you please tell the reason behind this? thanks

Comment: `/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root` is it your local machine path or HDFS path?

Comment: Its a local machine path.

Comment: Do you have HDFS in you sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I do have it

Comment: Try to put your file to some place on HDFS and indicate the full path in your code, e.g. `hdfs://path/to/file`